# Selectively apply nameprefix/namesuffix in kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Currently we are using ${HOME}/bin/kustomize edit set nameprefix prefix1

But it is adding nameprefix to all of our resources like deployment.yaml and service.yaml.

We want to apply nameprefix to deployment.yaml only and not apply it to service.yaml

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem. If not - please provide more details/yamls with your specific example.

Answer (score 12):

Posting for better visibility:

**If you are using**:

```
kustomize edit set nameprefix prefix1
```

This command will set ***namePrefix***  inside your current **kustomization**.
As stated in the question - this is the way how it works,  ***namePrefix*** will be used for all specified resources inside **kustomization.yaml**.

Please consider the following scenario using the idea of an **overlay** and **base** with kustomization.

```
Tested with:
kustomize/v4.0.1
```

Base declare resources and settings shared in common and overlay declare additional differences.

```
.
├── base
│   ├── [deployment.yaml]  Deployment nginx
│   ├── [kustomization.yaml]  Kustomization 
│   └── [service.yaml]  Service nginx
└── prod
    ├── [kustomization.yaml]  Kustomization 
    └── kustomizeconfig
        └── [deploy-prefix-transformer.yaml]  PrefixSuffixTransformer customPrefixer
```

- **base**: common files

```
#deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx

#service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    run: nginx

#kustomization.yaml
resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
```

- **overlay/prod**: kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
bases:
- ../../base
nameSuffix: -Suffix1
transformers:
- ./kustomizeconfig/deploy-prefix-transformer.yaml
```

- **overlay/prod/kustomizeconfig**: deploy-prefix-transformer.yaml

```
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
metadata:
  name: customPrefixer
prefix: "deploymentprefix-"
fieldSpecs:
- kind: Deployment
  path: metadata/name
```

As you can see, using this structure and builtin plugin **PrefixSuffixTransformer** you can get the desired effect:

```
kustomize build overlay/prod/
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx-Suffix1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploymentprefix-nginx-Suffix1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
```

This configuration (overlay/prod/kustomization.yaml) will apply **nameSuffix: -Suffix1** to all resources specified in **base** directory and using  [**PrefixSuffixTransformer**](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/extending_kustomize/builtins/#example-8) will add in this specific example **prefix: "deploymentprefix-"** to **deployment.metadata.name**

```
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
metadata:
  name: customPrefixer
prefix: "deploymentprefix-"
fieldSpecs:
- kind: Deployment
  path: metadata/name

 /kustomizeconfig/deploy-prefix-transformer.yaml
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for Zelando Postgres setup with config env with static name!

Comment: Just battling a very similar issue with `PrefixSuffixTransformer` and trying to get it add a suffix onto the namespaces with no success.

Using:

   apiVersion:builtin
   kind: PrefixSuffixTransformer
   metadata:
     name:  namespace-suffix
   suffix:  -mysuffixforNs
   fieldSpecs:
   - kind: Namespace
     path: metadata/name

Answer (score 2):

There is [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/519) about that

> is it possible to have kustomization file avoid adding prefixes to few kinds ?

And there are 2 examples provided by @jbrette with which you can achieve what you need.

- [no prefix to secret](https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/tree/allinone/examples/issues/issue_0519)
- [canary using skip](https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/tree/allinone/examples/issues/issue_0519_c)

Additionally you can take a look at these pull requests:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1232
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/pull/1491

Comment: What version of `kustomize` is this supposed to be working with? I just tested this with `kustomize/v3.8.7` and it does not seem to work at all. Oh, I just noticed they closed both PRs without merging. Sad face.

Comment: Does the `PrefixSuffixTransformer` work?  tried it on namespace objects and not able to get it working.  

Able to get it to amend the namespace used in objects but not the manifests to create the namespaces.  Using Kustomize v4.2.7

Answer (score -1):

For those who stumble across this, I had an issue get it to work with ServiceAccount type.
Issue was that I needed to prevent suffix from being added. Apparently namePrefix "should" prevent that too but in actuality I had to add:

```
nameSuffix:
- path: metadata/name
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: serviceaccount
  skip: true
```

Note kind type with lowercase. Using standard kind for `ServiceAccount` makes it to fail.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid syntax? 

`invalid type for kustomize.namePrefix: got "array", expected "string"`

https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/namesuffix/

Comment: If this was meant to be a `configuration`, then it also doesn't seem valid because `skip: true` is supported. :(