# Kustomize nameSuffix skip on some resources

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am using Kustomize to manage multiple variations of the same cluster. I am using `nameSuffix` option to add a suffix to all my resources:

```
nameSuffix: -mysfx
```

My problem is that everything works fine but adding this suffix only to one Service resource cause me an issue. My problem is that the application (Patroni) interact with a service that must be called:

```
CLUSTER-NAME-config
```

so I want to exclude this single resource from the `nameSuffix`. I know this is not possible due to how this feature was designed. I read several articles here on StackOverflow and on the web. I know I can skip the use of `nameSuffix` for a category of resources. So I tried to put in my `kustomization.yaml` the rows:

```
configurations:
- kustomize-config/kustomize-config.yaml
```

to skip all the Service resources. Then in the file `kustomize-config/kustomize-config.yaml`

```
nameSuffix:
- path: metadata/name
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  skip: true
```

but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this configuration?

Then suppose I am able now to skip the use of `nameSuffix` for only Service resources, I have other two Services where I want to add this suffix. What do I have to do to add `nameSuffix` to these two Services and not the one mentioned above?

If there is a better solution for this, please let me know.

Comment: Which version of `kustomize` do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skipping selected `kind`s doesn't work because this feature wasn't implemented - from [this comment on GitHub issue 519](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/519#issuecomment-527734888).

Also [this is an example](https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/tree/allinone/examples/issues/issue_0519#preparation-step-resource0) how it was supposed to be (what you tried)

---

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/519#issuecomment-557303870), it works on `kind`s that were explicitly mentioned:

> The plugin's config is currently oriented towards specifying which
> kinds to modify, ignoring others.

Also based on some tests I performed, it looks for `kind`s only, it doesn't look for names or anything, so only the whole `kind` can be included. Hence second part of your question is I'm afraid not possible (well, using kustomize, you can use `sed` for instance and modify everything you need on the go).

I created a simple structure and tested it:

```
$ tree
.
├── cm1.yaml
├── cm2.yaml
├── kustomization.yaml
├── kustomizeconfig
│   └── skip-prefix.yaml
├── pod.yaml
├── secret.yaml
└── storageclass.yaml

1 directory, 7 files
```

There are two configmaps, pod, secret and storageclass, total 5 objects.

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml 

namePrefix: prefix-
nameSuffix: -suffix
resources:
- cm1.yaml
- cm2.yaml
- secret.yaml
- pod.yaml
- storageclass.yaml
configurations:
- ./kustomizeconfig/skip-prefix.yaml
```

And configuration (specified explicitly all kinds except for configmaps). Also it's called `namePrefix`, however it works for both: `prefix` and `suffix`:

```
$ cat kustomizeconfig/skip-prefix.yaml 

namePrefix:
- path: metadata/name
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
- path: metadata/name
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
- path: metadata/name
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: StorageClass
```

Eventually `kustomize build .` looks like:

```
$ kustomize build .

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: prefix-local-storage-suffix # modified
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm1 # skipped
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm2 # skipped
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: prefix-secret-suffix # modified
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: prefix-pod-suffix # modified
spec:
  containers:
  - image: image
    name: pod
```

---

Another potential option is to use [`PrefixSuffixTransformer` plugin](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/extending_kustomize/builtins/#_prefixsuffixtransformer_) - it works differently in terms of specifying what `prefix` and/or `suffix` should be added and `fieldSpec`s where.

Please find an [example](https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/tree/allinone/examples/issues/issue_0519_b#preparation-step-resource10) and final results below within this Feature Test for Issue 0519_b.

Also there's already a [good answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66438033/15537201) about using `PrefixSuffixTransformer`.

Comment: in my case this somehow only added another namePrefix or nameSuffix to the specified ressource, e.g.: `prefix-prefix-secret-suffix`

I switched to another strategy, patching the names directly: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4156#issuecomment-909748440

Comment: This also repeated the suffix for me, rather than skipping it.

Comment: Same as the above two comments. Seems strange?

Comment: I have this exact problem. I'm not setting a suffix either. I think this 'configuration' file is merely adding additional routes to the prefixing strategy. For me, it's double prefixing everything in this configuration, AND prefixing things that aren't in this file once. Really makes me sad. This is a struggle.